# How to search in my followed posts?

Tags: support, feature-request, search

I just came across a question that's really similar to one I've seen before. However, I can't find it. I'm pretty sure I [followed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661) it, but after clicking through the first few pages of the "Following" screen I still can't find it.

| [image: 468 Followed posts] | [image: Followed posts split into 16 pages] |
| --- | --- |

Is there a way to **search** inside followed posts only? I think this question also applies to Bookmarks, Responses, and Votes.

Comment: *"I think this question also applies to Bookmarks, Responses, and Votes."* For bookmarks, use `inbookmarks:mine`, per [How do I search?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

Comment: Could the post have been deleted in the meantime? Visibility may or may not change above 10,000 reputation points.

Comment: @PeterMortensen possibly, but it wasn’t a bad question. It was about animating an image on a path using SwiftUI. I think there was an answer too.

Comment: I can still see questions I have followed that have since been deleted (in fact some questions I follow in case they are or have been been deleted), @PeterMortensen , however, I suspect the same is not true for the OP as they have less than <10K. Though they aren't far off, so we might find out soon if my suspicion is correct.

Comment: @Larnu sorry forgot to mention, deleted posts do show up in Followed for me. They just have a red tint and when I click on them, it says "Page not found". But I still haven't found the question that I'm looking for ;-;

Comment: I, in honesty, struggle to sometime find a post I visited the same day, or prior, in my browser history when I looks familiar, so I wouldn't worry too much. :)